# Tool to rename files with some logic involved

Tags: ubuntu, filenames, rename

Any command line tools to rename files that don't already contain a string or a set of strings to then include that string?

So all files in a given folder should have `high` in the name for "high priority", but some do and some don't. Rather than add it to all files, how may I first check to see if a file has `high` in the name then, if it doesn't, add it to the beginning of the name?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `bash`, then the pattern `!(*high*)` will match all names in the current directory that doesn't contain the string `high`, if the `extglob` shell option is set:

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ ls
1      2      3      4-high
$ ls -d -- !(*high*)
1 2 3
```

We may then loop over the names matching this pattern, renaming each matching name:

```
shopt -s extglob nullglob

for name in !(*high*); do
    [[ ! -f $name ]] && continue

    mv -- "$name" "high-$name"
done
```

What's happening here is that we set `extglob` and also `nullglob` (makes the globbing pattern disappear rather than be retained as-is if the pattern does not match) before the loop.  You could also enable `dotglob` if you want to rename hidden names as well.

The loop then skips any name that does not refer to a regular file (it may be a directory name, for example), and then inserts the string `high-` at the front of the name with `mv`.

The `--` in the `mv` command is to avoid interpreting any filenames that start with a dash as a set of options by mistake.

Running this on a set of test files:

```
$ ls
1      2      3      4-high
```

Just pasting in the code from above straight into the shell:

```
$ shopt -s extglob nullglob
$
$ for name in !(*high*); do
>     [[ ! -f $name ]] && continue
>
>     mv -- "$name" "high-$name"
> done
```

```
$ ls
4-high high-1 high-2 high-3
```

---

You could also use the Perl `rename` utility like so:

```
shopt -s extglob
rename -v 'if (-f) { s/^/high-/ }' -- !(*high*)
```

This would move the `-f` test of the loop in the first variation in this answer into Perl, but still uses the same filename globbing pattern to select the files to rename. The `-f` makes the renaming only affect regular files (no directories etc.)

---

A variation that does not rely on extended globbing patterns in the shell would be

```
rename -v 'if (-f && !/high/) { s/^/high-/ }' -- *
```

This simply does the test for whether the name already contains the string `high` inside the `rename` call, and skips renaming the file if it does occur.  The `*` glob selects all files in the current directory (apart from hidden ones).

Answer (score 1):

If you have GNU Parallel:

```
parallel mv {} '{= /high/ or $_="high$_" =}' ::: *
```

Comment: What is the benefit of `parallel` here?

Comment: The syntax. So if you already have GNU Parallel installed and you do not have perl `rename` installed, you can use that instead. In other words: the parallelization part is not the goal.

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
zmv '^*high*' 'high-$f'
```

With case-insensitive matching:

```
zmv '^*(#i)high*' 'high-$f'
```